# Algorithm to find sequence in longer number

Tags: javascript, algorithm

this is a tough one.
I haven't been able to work it out for quite some time now, so now I am hoping some of you might know an answer.
I have a long number a bit like this one here:

**122111312121142113121**

There are no numbers higher than four or lower than one.
Now I need to find out if a random sequence (random numbers, but nothing other than 1-4, and random length) exists within that longer number.
As an example I have the sequence **13121211** and I need to find out if it is in the above array (In this case it is, but there's always a chance it isn't!).
Unfortunately I am limited to only using pure HTML and JavaScript, no jQuery or any Frameworks like AngularJS.
The number has about 600 characters, so a solution without having to type all those into an array would be awesome!
I feel like there should be an easy way to solve this, but I just can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance !  :)

Comment: Interesting question. I can tell you that if you generate a random sequence of length `n` then you expect a sequence of Theta(log n) consecutive characters (e.g. ~log n consecutive 1's); however, this is an asymptotic result.

Comment: convert them to strings and look into using `indexOf()`

Comment: I should point out that the question belongs to statistics SE. Do the wiki pages [randomness tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) and [statistical randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness) help? (Once you have an algorithm you shouldn't have trouble coding it.)

Comment: I think Knuth's TAOCP Vol. 2 contains a good discussion of this subject.

Comment: He doesn't mean "random", he means "given".  OP, change this in your question as "random" means something very different.

Comment: I'll try it with `indexOf()`, thanks @IrkenInvader

Comment: Held off cause I thought it might be homework but now i'm confused about why it is tough, is this it? https://jsfiddle.net/oyys1nd9/

Comment: @j_random_hacker the long number is given, the short sequence is completely random and constantly changes.

Comment: @IrkenInvader I did'nt know about `indexOf()`, so I thought it would be tougher than this too. After some research on `IndexOf()` I found out that it can give me the position of the sequence in the string too, which would be optimal for my case.

Comment: @Hba: The short string is still *given* though, from the point of view of your program.  Isn't it?

Comment: If you know what you're looking for, then that looked-for thing is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate random strings and search the `bigNumber` for them.

`minSubstr` is the minimum length of the random string we check

`maxSubstr` is its maximum length

`numTries` is how many random strings we test

All matching strings are thrown into our output div.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oyys1nd9/2/)

**JS**

```
var bigNumber = "122111312121142113121";    
var output = document.getElementById("output");    
var minSubstr = 4;
var maxSubstr = 6;
var numTries = 1000;

function findNumbers(){
  for(var i = 0; i < numTries; i++){
    var num = getRandNum();
    if(bigNumber.indexOf(num) !== -1) output.innerHTML += num + ' <br/>';
  }
}

function getRandNum(){
  var ret = '';
  var len = getRandom(minSubstr, maxSubstr);
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    ret += getRandom(1,4);
  }
  return ret;
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

findNumbers();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the long number? If it's a number, it's just a matter of string conversion:

```
// Really there should be some type check
function numberContainsSequence(number, sequence) {
  return ("" + number).contains("" + sequence);
}

numberContainsSequence(122111312121142113121, 13121211); // -> true
```

If you already have a string, it's even easier, but the same function will do.

If you have an array of chars or ints, just use join:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].join(''); // -> "123456"
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'].join(''); // -> "123456"
```

Comment: A number of 600 digits isn’t really possible in JavaScript. It would have to be a string which can be of any length. Also, I’m not aware of a native `contains` method in JavaScript. See my answer below …

Comment: Ad a matter of fact, contains works in Chrome. But yes, you are right about indexOf(sequence)>=0.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.indexOf(sequence), where string and sequence are defined by you. If this returns -1, the sequence is not contained in the string. As @A. Chiesa mentions, .indexOf() needs two strings, so you may need to use the .join() function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you’re just looking for one string inside another. JavaScript numbers don’t allow 600 digits, but that’s OK, since you’re not treating it as a number anyway — just a sequence of characters.

Try something like this:

```
var number='122111312121142113121';
var search='13121211';
var position=number.indexOf(search);
if(position>-1) alert('Found at '+position);
else alert('Not Found');
```

The `indexOf` method is doing all of the hard work. A failure is indicated by an index of `-1`, since the index is zero-based, meaning that the first successful position is `0`.

And you’re right in avoiding jQuery of Angular for this problem, which is like trying to crack a walnut with a thermo-nuclear device.

Edit: *Modern* JavaScript has an `includes` method which returns `true` or `false` rather than a position. Not IE, of course.